Power automate - remove last line break from a string output
I have a string builder which builds a string with next line (line break). Need help in removing the last line break from a string output.
From below example, need to remove "\n" just after File Server Access:
"1. FNPF eMail/OWA\n2. LiveLink/Content Server\n3. Photo Enquiry\n4. Internet Access\n5. File Server Access\n"



You can use the trim() function.
See trim for more info.
